# Why does the jQuery script in the partial view not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

(**I will left out some of the code in which I'm 100% sure in order to make the code more compact**) I have a main view (the main view doesn't have any html-head-body because it is included in Layout)...

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div id="user-files-table-wrapper">
        <!-- Partial view for user file management to be rendered there-->
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/user-files-table-style.css"/>

@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/user-file-manager.js"></script>
}
```

..and a Partial view

```
<h3>User files ("Delete" and "Download" buttons can be clicked with invalid XML files only)</h3>
<table id="user-devices-table">
    <tr>
        <th>User file</th>
        <th>Assigned email</th>
        <th>Is valid</th>
        <th>Delete button</th>
        <th>Download button</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var userFileViewModel in Model)
    {
        @foreach (var file in userFileViewModel.UserFiles)
        {
                if (isValid == false && isXml)
                {
                    <tr class="user-file-row invalid">
                        <td>@file.FileName</td>
                        <td>@userFileViewModel.Email</td>
                        <td>@file.IsValid</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-userFileId="@file.UserFileID" asp-route-fileName="@file.FileName">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" id="@file.FileName" class="btn btn-primary download-button" value="Download" />
                            <p class="download-result">File has been downloaded successfully</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        }
    }
</table>
```

...and some JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".btn.btn-primary.download-button", function () {
        const fileName = $(this).attr("id");
        const clickedButtonRowIndex = $("input[type='button']").index(this);

        downloadUserFile(fileName, clickedButtonRowIndex);
    });
});

function downloadUserFile(fileName, rowIndex) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Admin/Download",
        data: { fileName: fileName },
        success: function (data) {
            processProvidedFile(data, fileName);
            showDownloadResult(rowIndex);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(`An error occured: ${error.responseText}`);
        }
    });
}

function processProvidedFile(data, fileName) {
    fetch(data)
        .then(resp => resp.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.style.display = "none";
            a.href = url;
            a.download = fileName;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        })
        .catch(() => alert("An error occured"));
}

function showDownloadResult(rowIndex) {
    $(".download-result.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".download-result").eq(rowIndex).addClass("active");
}
```

...and some CSS:

```
.download-result {
    display: none;
}

    .download-result.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

In general, my task is to download the file and show that the file has been successfully downloaded. Files are downloaded normally, no problem with it. My issue is that the `showDownloadResult(rowIndex)` function not working as expected. Chrome debugger hits it with a correct `rowIndex`, but neither remove an `active` class nor adding it. I checked the function in JSFiddle - it works as expected there, but not in my partial view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your partial view updated dynamically with JS? If that is the case then $(document).ready will not be executed, you will need to execute $(document).on on the new html yourself.

Comment: @the_lotus I got your point. Well, yes, my partial view is updating by HTML (I have a `$("#user-files-table-wrapper").html(data);` in some of my JS. But what do I have to make it work? Can you please show me some example? I am not actually experienced with such issues